# Error con método Prepare PHP PDO NULL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Verán tengo el siguiente código donde a través del cual tengo una clase que contiene un método para generar la conexión; otra clase que hereda de la primera y me ayudará a generar una nueva inserción.

Declaré como protegida la propiedad conexión y se supone que de ese modo tanto la clase que la declara como la que hereda tienen acceso a ella; muestro mi código

```
<?php

class Conexion 
{
    protected static $conexion;
    public function conectando($conexion)
    {
        $this->conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=demo", "root", "******");
    }
}

class Insertar extends Conexion
{
    private $name;
    private $attributes;
    private $insertar;
    public function inserta($name, $attributes)
    {
        $this->insertar = parent::$conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO product(name, attributes) VALUES(:name, :attributes)");
        $insertar->bindParam(':name', $this->name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $insertar->bindParam(':attributes', $this->attributes, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $insertar->execute();
    }
}

$registroUno = new Insertar;
$registroUno->inserta( "data", "saludos");
```

Sin embargo después de probar la instancia, cuando ejecuto el archivo desde consola, me devuelve el siguiente error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare()
>   on null in line 19

Aclaro la línea 19 es donde hago uso de **PREPARE**

También les comento que ya revise las respuestas a otras preguntas similares pero me encuentro confundido respecto a aplicar la solución ahí mostrada

AÑADO CON LA AYUDA DE A.CEDANO LA RESPUESTA QUE OBTUVE AL HACER UN VAR_DUMP()

```
object(Insertar)#1 (3) {
  ["name":"Insertar":private]=>
  NULL
  ["attributes":"Insertar":private]=>
  NULL
  ["insertar":"Insertar":private]=>
  NULL
}
```

Comment: La instancia de conexión se crea cuando invocas este método: `conectando`, por tanto, si no lo invocas nunca se creará. Puedes hacerlo usando el mismo objeto `$registroUno`, ya que éste extiende de la clase `conexion`. Por ejemplo:  `$registroUno = new Insertar;` y conectas antes de insertar: `$registroUno->conectar("¿necesitas este parámetro);` Otra cosa es que, no veo el sentido de pedir un parámetro en el método `conectar`. Y otra cosa, dado que en la clase `$conexion` es una variable `static`, no puedes referirte a ella con `$this`, debes usar `self`, aquí: `self::$conexion = new PDO(...)`

Comment: ok @A.Cedano probaré y te comento, gracias por el apoyo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay varios problemas en el código. Los iré indicando por orden:

- Si en la clase `Conexion` has declarado esta variable así:

  ```
  protected static $conexion;
  ```

  Luego no puedes referirte a ella usando `$this`, puesto que es estática. Debes usar `self`.
- No veo qué utilidad tendría la variable `$conexion` que recibe tu método `conectando` como parámetro... salvo entorpecer el código. ¿Le vas a pasar al método lo que él mismo debería crear?
- Para tener a mano una instancia de la conexión, debes invocar al método que crea esa instancia, por supuesto. Dado que `Insertar` extiende de `Conexion`, entonces puedes usar la misma instancia de `Insertar` para conectar. O... puedes invocar `conectar` desde dentro del método `inserta` si lo prefieres.
- No veo qué utilidad tendría el uso de una propiedad `$insertar` dentro de la clase `Insertar`. Creo que se podría usar una variable (`$stmt`), como se suele hacer habitualmente. Pues `$insertar` sería una especia de miembro fantasma en tu clase que no serviría para transferir o usar en ninguna parte.
- En la clase `Insertar` tampoco estás asignado los valores que recibes en el método `insertar` a los miembros de la clase. Es posible que haga falta un replanteamiento de la clase, estudiando si no es más conveniente pasar los valores de los miembros en el constructor. Por el momento, solamente asignaré los valores a los miembros en el método referido, para no modificar demasiado tu clase.

El código quedaría entonces así:

```
<?php

class Conexion 
{
    protected static $conexion;
    public function conectando()
    {
        self::$conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=demo", "root", "******");
    }
}

class Insertar extends Conexion
{
    private $name;
    private $attributes;
    private $insertar; //en vez de esto he optado por usar un $stmt dentro del método inserta
    public function inserta($name, $attributes)
    {

        /*
           *Aquí asignamos los parámetros a cada miembro
           *quizá esto sea algo más propio del constructor
           *o de métodos más específicos como insertarPersona, insertarEmpresa
           *aquí no tiene demasiado sentido, porque incluso puedes usar las mismas
           *variables $name y $attributes en los bindParam
        */
        $this->name=$name;
        $this->attributes=$attributes;

        $stmt = parent::$conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO product(name, attributes) VALUES(:name, :attributes)");
        $stmt->bindParam(':name', $this->name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':attributes', $this->attributes, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}

$registroUno = new Insertar;
$registroUno->conectando();
$registroUno->inserta( "data", "saludos");
```

Comment: me aparece el error de undefined variable $insertar y también este error PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bindParam() on null in

Comment: @AlfredoPaz ya, es que faltaban `$this` en los otros métodos, dentro de `inserta`. De todos modos, he cambiado eso por una variable `$stmt`, como se hace normalmente. No tiene ninguna utilidad usar un miembro de la clase para el statement, a no ser que lo vayas a querer transferir como tal a otra parte del código, lo cual es poco probable. Revisa la respuesta editada.

Comment: gracias @A.Cedano te comento ya superé esa parte sin embargo no me logra insertar, el tipo de datos es correcto así como los valores de conexión; además por consola no arroja ni errores ni warnings

Comment: ¿No estará la inserción violando una restricción de registro ya existente o algo así? ¿El nombre de tabla y de columnas es correcto? ¿Está conectado correctamente? Puedes agregar un `errorInfo` si quieres depurar.

Comment: si de decho es parte de un ejercicio de auto estudio (nada escolar aclaro), solo es una tabla y los nombres de las columnas y datos es correcto; hice un var_dump y lo agrego en mi pregunta para que cheques que me salió

Comment: Ohhh ya, es que en la clase `Insertar` tampoco estás asignado los valores a los miembros de la clase. Ahora edito.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78960/discussion-between-alfredo-paz-and-a-cedano).

Answer (score 0):

Un detalle simple:

No invocas al método conectando() de modo que la conexión PDO na se ha creado.
Por esa razón es null.

Solución en el constructor (la clase no tiene uno explícito) invocarlo

```
<?php

class Conexion
// atributos miembros
public function __constuct(){
    // Leer los parametros para conectar en un directorio protegido
    // así se hace en ZF2,3
    $coneccion_params = leer_en_directorio_protegido();
    $this->conectando($coneccion_params);
}
// Nota pase este método a protegido
protected function conectando($coneccion_params){
    // usar los parametros para crear la cadena de conexion a pasar a PDO

    // Lo demás como está en tu código
}
```

Comment: pudieras explicarme mejor tu respuesta? por favor, no comprendo leer_en_directorios....

Comment: leer_en_directorio_protegido() es un nombre arbitrario para indicar una acción necesaria, en un directorio privado, (protegido del acceso público) deben guardarse las credenciales de base de datos, usualmente dos archivos, uno p.ej global.php con los datos de nombre de bd, path, etc y otro p.ej local.php con datos de usuario y password. El método los lee mediante un llamado de tipo fopen() y configura los parametros necesarios para iniciar PDO.

Comment: te comprendo pero te comento que no estoy leyendo archivo alguno por lo cual no entiendo el por que de la instrucción fopen

Comment: porque vas a pasar a protected el método público conectando() y necesitas la información de conexión que está ROM en el mismo; imagino que por esa razón tiene el parámetro $conexion que de momento no se usa para crearla, pero que posiblemente en el futuro traiga la información requerida para conectar y se implemente su uso en el método.

Comment: De esa manera, puedes tener una parte fija de la información de bd en global.php y en varios local_x.php información para usuarios con distintos privilegios de acceso a la bd. O variando un poco información para acceso a múltiples BD.