# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare()

Tags: php, pdo

Tengo un pequeño error, con una consulta. He visto muchos tutos relacionados aquí en Stack Overflow, pero aún no logro dar con la solución.

```
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/modelo/conection/conection.php';

class User extends Database
{
    private $password;
    private $username;

    function __construct() { }

    public function userExists($username)
    {
        $query = $this->connect()->prepare('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE username =     :username');
        $query->execute(['username' => $username]);
        if ($query->rowCount()) {
            echo "existe";
            return true;
        } else {
            echo "no existe";
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Y este es mi conexión.

```
function connect()
{
    try {
        $connection = "mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db . ";charset=" . $this->charset;
        $options = [
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE          => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
        ];
        $pdo = new PDO($connection, $this->user, $this->password, $options);
        return $pdo;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        print_r('Error connection 2.0: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Estoy usando la versión 7.4 de PHP.

Este es mi error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare()
> on null in

Comment: La funcion la tienes en el mismo archivo o en otra parte?

Comment: la conexion esta en conection.php, y esta funcion esta en user.php

Comment: @alvarowhite usa un require para llamarlo asi:  `require "conexion.php";`

Comment: si. la conexion es una clase. y user es la otra clase

Comment: Entonces usa otro require que diga `require "user.php";`

Comment: estoy llamando la conexion con la ruta adsoluta.require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/modelo/conection/conection.php';

Comment: mi user extiende de databse  class User extends Database{

Comment: Si observas bien el error te indica que la funcion prepare esta en blanco, comprueba que los estes relacionando bien, sobre las clases creo que tienes que llamarlas antes de usar el prepare

Comment: asi lo hago, amigo Bruno Levet, ya he revisado todo varias veces y no encuentro el error. si estoy llamando. de user extiendo de database.php. y antes de estender requiero esa conexion

Comment: Creo que ya lo descifre, tu llamas antes de extender, cuando deberias extender antes de llamar, si me comentas que tipo de sistema estas intentando hacer tambien seria util

Comment: Encontre algo que te puede ayudar: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/173553/error-con-m%c3%a9todo-prepare-php-pdo-null?rq=1

Comment: nada aun amigo.  mira esta es mi clase user.php, aqui esta completa. voy a actualizar la pregunta para agregarle la clase user.php completa. no entendi la parte de inicializar antes de extender

Comment: que tipo de sistema quieres hacer?

Comment: estoy haciendo un login. luego sera una aplicacion para vender servicios, algo como mudanzas, reparaciones del hogar etc.

Comment: Podrias optar por un codigo mas simple, yo de hecho estoy haciendo algo parecido

Comment: claro Bruno Levet. me podrias ayudar con algo mas simple por favor

Comment: Claro te lo pongo como respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Podrias intentar esto:

HTML:

```
<?php 

include_once "templates/header.php"; //Aqui reemplazas por tus estilos

?>

<div class="register-box">
  <div class="register-logo">
    <a href="#"><b>Admin</b>Dashboard</a>
  </div>

  <div class="register-box-body">
    <p class="login-box-msg">Login</p>

    <form method="post">
      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input type="email" name="Usuario" class="form-control" placeholder="Usuario">
        <span class="fa fa-user form-control-feedback"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input type="password" name="Pass" class="form-control" placeholder="Contraseña">
        <span class="fa fa-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <!-- /.col -->
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Ingresar | <span class="fa fa-lock"></span></button>
        </div>

        <!-- /.col -->
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <?php if (!empty($errores)): ?>
      <?php echo $errores ?>
    <?php endif ?> //Aqui muestras errores
  <!-- /.form-box -->
</div>
    
<!-- /.register-box -->
```

Este es el PHP

```
<?php session_start();

require "admin.php";
require "functions.php"; //Estos son los archivos de las funciones y la conexion

$errores = "";

if (isset($_SESSION["usuario"])) {
    header("Location: funcion_dashboard.php");
}

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $usuario = $_POST["Usuario"];
    $pass = $_POST["Pass"];
    $pass = hash("sha512", $pass);

if (empty($usuario) or empty($pass)) {
        $errores = '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4><i class="icon fa fa-ban"></i> Alert!</h4>
                        Porfavor llena los campos.
              </div>';
    } else {

$conexion = conexion($bd_config);

    $statement = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM Login WHERE Usuario = :Usuario AND Pass = :Pass AND Estatus = 'Activo' ");
    $statement->execute(array(":Usuario" => $usuario, ":Pass" => $pass));

    $resultado = $statement->fetch();   

    if ($resultado !== false) {

    $statement = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM Login UsuarioID WHERE Usuario = :Usuario AND Pass = :Pass AND Estatus = 'Activo' ");
    $statement->execute(array(":Usuario" => $usuario, ":Pass" => $pass));

    $resultado = $statement->fetch();

        $_SESSION["ID"] = $resultado["UsuarioID"];

        $_SESSION["usuario"] = $usuario;
        header("Location: funcion_dashboard.php");

    } else {
        $errores .= '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible">
                     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                     <h4><i class="icon fa fa-ban"></i> Alert!</h4>
                            El usuario o la contraseña no son correctos.
                    </div>';
        }
    }
}

require "login.php";

 ?>
```

Funciones:

conexion:

```
function conexion($bd_config){
try {
    $conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=".$bd_config["basedatos"], $bd_config["usuario"], $bd_config["pass"]);
    return $conexion;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    return false;
}
}
```

Credenciales de la BD

```
<?php  

$bd_config = array(
    "basedatos" => "tu base de datos",
    "usuario" => "tu usuario",
    "pass" => "tu password"
);

?>
```

Solo cambia las consultas ya que yo uso AdminLTE

Comment: te agradesco amigo, pero no es la solucion que busco

Answer (score 0):

les comento que ya logre corregir mi el problema...
aqui les va la solucion por si a alguien mas le sucede lo mismo.

me cree dos variables de clase

```
private $con;
private $conection;
```

y en el constructor inicialice estas variables,

```
function __construct() {
    $this->con = new Connection();
    $this->conection = $this->con->connect();
```

}

y ya lo demas fue todo igual.

```
$consult = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE username=:username";

    $query = $this->conection->prepare($consult);
    $query->execute();
```

quizas no sea la forma mas optima, pero me funciono.
espero que tambien le funcione igual que a mi :)

Answer (score 0):

Ese error es que la conexión no se esta dando, no muestras tu clase Database, pero supongo que en esa clase tiene su función __construct() que es donde le das el valor a los atributos de tu clase Database, básicamente la función connect() usa esos atributos al momento de la conexion.

```
$connection = "mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db . ";charset=" . $this->charset;
```

Entonces cuando heredas esa la Clase Database, puedes usar esa función connect(), pero esos valores que le diste en tu funcion __construct() se pondrán como nulos, por lo mismo que le diste esos valores en la funcion __construct(),
por eso, al momento de heredar la clase Database tienes que hacer que se ejecute su método constructor.

```
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/modelo/conection/conection.php';

class User extends Database
{
    private $password;
    private $username;

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function userExists($username)
    {
        $query = $this->connect()->prepare('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE username =     :username');
        $query->execute(['username' => $username]);
        if ($query->rowCount()) {
            echo "existe";
            return true;
        } else {
            echo "no existe";
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Con ejecutar parent::__construct(), estas haciendo que se ejecute la clase constructora de tu clase Database, y ya sus atributos no los estaría retornando como nulo, y ya no habría problema al momento de usar la función connect().